# How to detect when a Switch is slided, not clicked

Tags: android, user-interface, view, switch-statement

I managed to capture when a Switch View is clicked so the main activity responds accordingly; but whenever I slide it instead of clicking it's as if nothing has happened. How can I detect this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having previously implemented the Switch button adding

```
android:onClick="onSwitchClicked"
```

On my .xml manifest and adding the corresponding method to my main activity did not provide desired results; since as the question says it only worked when clicked. Noticed that it is better to do it this way:

```
powerSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    //code
                }else{
                    //code
                }
            }
        });
```

This way, whenever the Switch's state changes, regardless of sliding or clicking, the method will be called.

Refer to this tutorial for further information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution you found, still a bit unclear: the manifest inclusion from the first code snippet is NOT necessary to include in your code what is in the second code snippet, it is (one of the ways) to implement an onClickListener - unrelateded to the OnCheckedChangeListener